# What is Chinese for CFD (Contract for Difference)?

Tags: translation, word

Is there a term for CFD (Contract for Difference in stock trading) in Chinese?

I googled it but could not find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[差价合约（Ccontract For Difference,CFD）](http://wiki.mbalib.com/wiki/%E5%B7%AE%E4%BB%B7%E5%90%88%E7%BA%A6)

> 差价合约是一种比较新兴的金融衍生工具，目前只在7个国家的证券交易所交易。投资者以某一个商品的价格进行买卖，而不涉及该商品实体的交易。差价合约的商品，理论上可以是所有有浮动价格的东西，包括有各国指数，外汇，期货，股票，贵重金属以及其他商品。

[股指差价合约(Contract for Difference)](http://www.financeun.com/News/201557/2013cfn/13394143600.shtml)
[差價合約- 维基百科，自由的百科全书](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B7%AE%E5%83%B9%E5%90%88%E7%B4%84)